# Getting Celery Group Results in a Flask App

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm using flask, have a simple app set up, and am trying to learn how to leverage celery effectively to do work, and when queried, show results.

In the most basic example, I was creating a single task, via `task.delay(args)`. This object then let me pull an ID for the job, which I could query for later by hitting a different endpoint. Simple.

My goal is to mimic this, though utilizing groups. Reading the docs, I see that the group primitive is lazy, so I have to actually call it before I can save it.

My question I'm sure comes from a lack of understanding, but basically is: 
If my goal is being able to run groups of background task asynchronously and in parallel via a flask Pipeline, how do I then retrieve `.join()` results for the group given the following constraints

- Request Endpoint1 (probably return an ID)
- Request Endpotin2, passing ID to return result from work done

Is this the correct way to do this? Or is there a different mindset I should being thinking in?

Psuedo code:

```
# From my apps init
celery_instance = Celery("module.modulename", backend = app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], broker = app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery_instance.conf.update(app.config)

<snip>

from celery import group
from app import celery_instance

@app.route("/status/domain/<id>", methods=['GET'])
def query(id):
  # Works for single job, not job group
  result = celery_instance.AsyncResult(id)
  ...

@app.route("/query/domain/<domain>", methods=['GET'])
def query_by_domain(domain):
  ...
  job = group([task1.delay(domain), task2.delay(domain)])
  return redirect(url_for('app.query', id=job.id), code=302)
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the exact same thing on Flask. Did you find a way?

Comment: Nope, I never did unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to save group-result as through `GroupResult.save()` method:

```
@app.route("/query/domain/<domain>", methods=['GET'])
def query_by_domain(domain):
    ...
    job = group([task1.delay(domain), task2.delay(domain)])
    <b>job.save()</b>
    return redirect(url_for('app.query', id=job.id), code=302)
```

Then you can get `GroupResult` as through `GroupResult.restore()` method.

```
@app.route("/status/domain/<id>", methods=['GET'])
def query(id):
    # Works for single job, not job group
    <b>result = celery_instance.GroupResult.restore(group_id)</b>
    ...
```